# merging endpoints of a range with a sequence

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

In one of my application there is a piece of code that retrieve information from a `data.table` object depending on values in another.

```
# say this table contains customers details
dt <- data.table(id=LETTERS[1:4],
                 start=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-04-01"), "month"),
                 end=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-04-01"), "month") + c(6,8,10,5),
                 key="id")

# this one has some historical details
dt1 <- data.table(id=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=120),
                  date=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-04-30"), "day"),
                  var=rnorm(120),
                  key="id,date")

# and here I finally retrieve my historical information based one customer detail
#
library(data.table)

myfunc <- function(x) {
  # some code
  period <- seq(x$start, x$end, "day")
  dt1[.(x$id, period)][, mean(var)]
  # some code
}
```

to get the result for all I use `adply`

```
library(plyr)
library(microbenchmark)
> adply(dt, 1, myfunc)
   id      start        end         V1
1:  A 2010-01-01 2010-01-07  0.3143536
2:  B 2010-02-01 2010-02-09 -0.5796084
3:  C 2010-03-01 2010-03-11  0.1171404
4:  D 2010-04-01 2010-04-06  0.2384237

> microbenchmark(adply(dt, 1, myfunc))
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 adply(dt, 1, myfunc) 8.812486 8.998338 9.105776 9.223637 88.14057   100
```

Do you know a way to avoid the `adply` call and do the above in one `data.table` statement? Or anyway a faster method? (title edit suggestion more than welcome, I couldn't think a better one, thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great spot to use the `roll` argument of `data.table`:

```
setkey(dt1, id, date)
setkey(dt, id, start)

dt[dt1, roll = TRUE][end >= start,
   list(start = start[1], end = end[1], result = mean(var)), by = id]

# benchmark
microbenchmark(OP    = adply(dt, 1, myfunc),
               Frank = dt[dt1[as.list(dt[,seq.Date(start,end,"day"),by="id"])][,mean(var),by=id]],
               eddi  = dt[dt1, roll = TRUE][end >= start,list(start = start[1], end = end[1], result = mean(var)), by = id])
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#    OP 24.436126 29.184786 30.853094 32.493521 50.898664   100
# Frank  9.115676 11.303691 12.081000 13.122753 28.370415   100
#  eddi  5.336315  6.323643  6.771898  7.497285  9.531376   100
```

The time difference will become much more dramatic as the size of the datasets grows.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a bunch of nested `[.data.table` calls:

```
set.seed(1)
require(data.table)
# generate dt, dt1 as above
dt[
    dt1[
        as.list(dt[,seq.Date(start,end,"day"),by="id"])
    ][,mean(var),by=id]
]

#    id      start        end          V1
# 1:  A 2010-01-01 2010-01-07  0.04475859
# 2:  B 2010-02-01 2010-02-09 -0.01681972
# 3:  C 2010-03-01 2010-03-11  0.39791318
# 4:  D 2010-04-01 2010-04-06  0.77854732
```

I'm using `as.list` to unset the key. I wonder if there's a better way than this...

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(plyr)
microbenchmark(
    adply=adply(dt, 1, myfunc),
    dtdtdt= dt[dt1[as.list(dt[,seq.Date(start,end,"day"),by="id"])][,mean(var),by=id]]
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#   adply 12.987334 13.247374 13.477386 14.371258 18.362505   100
#  dtdtdt  4.854708  4.944596  4.993678  5.233507  7.082461   100
```

**EDIT:** (eddi) Alternatives to the above that would require one less merge (as discussed in comments) are:

```
setkey(dt, NULL)

dt1[dt[, list(seq.Date(start,end,"day"), end), by=id]][,
    list(start = date[1], end = end[1], result = mean(var)), by = id]
# or
dt1[dt[, seq.Date(start,end,"day"), by=id]][,
    list(start = date[1], end = date[.N], result = mean(var)), by = id]
```

Comment: You can make this a bit more clear if you return `end` in the first `[]` in addition to the sequence, then you won't need to do the last merge. Another option is calculating `end` from the `by`. In either case you'd be able to get rid of the `as.list` or `setkey` in that expression by unsetting the key for `dt` before starting.

Comment: @eddi returning `end` together with the sequence should give the same as your first `[]` with `nomatch=0` innit? Anyway thanks both, you were **very** helpful!

Comment: @Michele, I'm not sure which step you're talking about, but at some point they do converge :)

Comment: @eddi I'd characterize my solution as cumbersome, too :) [as you did in your initial comment, according to my inbox.] I don't really understand how to return `end` in a way that makes the merge I'm attempting work. Feel free to edit it in so I find out. I guess, besides being faster, your `roll` method wouldn't produce `NA` when days in the start-end range fail to show up in dt1, which is nice.  I never really knew what these `roll` and `nomatch` arguments were for. +1 to question and answer for illustrating.

Comment: @eddi I mean `dt[dt1, roll = TRUE, nomatch=0][end >= start]` and `dt[, list(seq.Date(start,end,"day"), end),by="id"]`. With the difference that yours will have also the `var` column and Frank's needs an additional join the get that, so the difference time probably.

Comment: @Michele the main difference there is that the first expression will only fill whatever is already in `dt1`, while the second one will fill in the full sequence regardless of whether it's in `dt1` or not

Comment: @eddi right, I see. In the most general case you perfectly right. I said that 'cause in my real case the sequence from `start` to `end` is expected to be entirely found in `dt1`'s `date` column, and my need is just to extract the relative values in `var`.