# How to merge two tables by date range and ID?

Tags: r, date, merge

I have a person table of individual characteristics e.g.:

```
person <- data.frame(group.id = c("N","N","P"), person.id = c("A", "B", "C"), strt = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2004-06-23")), end = c(as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2004-09-01"), as.Date(x = "2006-07-01")), c = 1:3, d = 3:5)
```

and a group table of group characteristics e.g.:

```
group <- data.frame(group.id = c("N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "P", "P", "P"), report.date = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-09-01")), a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6))
```

I'd like to merge them by the group.id and applicable date range e.g.:

```
group2 <- data.frame(group, person.id = c("A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), strt = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), end = c(as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d = c(3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

> ```
>   group.id report.date a b person.id       strt        end  c  d
> 1        N  2002-07-01 1 4         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 2        N  2002-08-01 2 5         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 3        N  2002-09-01 3 6         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 4        O  2002-07-01 1 4      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 5        O  2002-08-01 2 5      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 6        O  2002-09-01 3 6      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 7        P  2002-07-01 1 4      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 8        P  2002-08-01 2 5      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 9        P  2002-09-01 3 6      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> ```

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to do that in R?

Comment: You can use `data.table` and use [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560500/data-table-merge-based-on-date-ranges)

Comment: HI @Hack-R , I merged `person` and `group` using the common variable `group.id` and by checking whether `group$report.date` fell between the `person$strt` `person$end` range. In my example, I left the values from row 4 and below NA because they didn't have a corresponding value in the example `person` table.

Comment: @timothy.s.lau Thanks, I just updated my answer based on that explanation. Please see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
person <- data.frame(group_id = c("N","N","P"), person_id = c("A", "B", "C"), strt = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2004-06-23")), end = c(as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2004-09-01"), as.Date(x = "2006-07-01")), c = 1:3, d = 3:5)

group <- data.frame(group_id = c("N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "P", "P", "P"), report_date = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-09-01")), a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6))

group2 <- data.frame(group, person_id = c("A", "A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), strt = c(as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), as.Date(x = "2002-07-01"), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), end = c(as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), as.Date(x = "2003-08-01"), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d = c(3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))


library(sqldf)


sqldf("select a.*, b.* from 'group' a left join person b on a.group_id = b.group_id and (a.report_date >= b.strt and a.report_date <= b.end)")
```

> ```
>   group_id report_date a b group_id person_id       strt        end  c  d
> 1        N  2002-07-01 1 4        N         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 2        N  2002-08-01 2 5        N         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 3        N  2002-09-01 3 6        N         A 2002-07-01 2003-08-01  1  3
> 4        O  2002-07-01 1 4     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 5        O  2002-08-01 2 5     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 6        O  2002-09-01 3 6     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 7        P  2002-07-01 1 4     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 8        P  2002-08-01 2 5     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> 9        P  2002-09-01 3 6     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> NA NA
> ```

Note that `group` is a reserved word so I had to put it in single quotes to use it as a table. I also changed the `.`s in the column names to `_` to avoid problems, but you could've left the `.` and quoted all of the column names instead.

Comment: report date for group id P doesn't fall between strt and end

Comment: @timothy.s.lau Please hit refresh on your browser

Comment: Hi, on mobile. I'll run your code when I get back to my office though, thanks

Comment: This looks good. I was struggling to figure out how to do this in base R. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Note that SQL also accepts this: `a.report_date between b.strt and b.end`