# sum values ​of a joined table between two dates with data table

Tags: r, data.table

We want to complete a DT1 table, by retrieving the sum of scores contained in another DT2 table.
By adding to DT1 counters A and B from DT2, making sure that date of DT1 is between the start and end date of DT2.
How is this achievable with data table?

## Initial data

```
Table DT1

Date        City   Squad
2022/1/5    NY     a
2022/1/6    NY     b
2022/1/9    LA     b
2022/1/7    NY     a
2022/1/5    NY     a

Table DT2

Date_start  Date_end   City  Squad   Counter_A   Counter_B
2022/1/1    2022/1/11   NY    a        1           1 
2022/1/2    2022/1/5    NY    a        2           3 
2022/1/1    2022/1/8    LA    b        2           1 
2022/1/1    2022/1/8    NY    b        1           3
```

## Expected result

```
Date        City   Squad   Counter_A   Counter_B
2022/1/5     NY       a      3          4 
2022/1/6     NY       b      1          3 
2022/1/9     LA       b      0          0 
2022/1/7     NY       a      1          1
```

## Init data code

```
require(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(
  work_day = c("2022/1/5","2022/1/6","2022/1/9","2022/1/7","2022/1/7","2022/1/3"),
  city= c("NY", "NY","LA", "NY", "NY", "NY"),
  squad=c("a","b","b","a","a","a")
)

DT2 <- data.table(
  date_start = c("2022/1/1","2022/1/2","2022/1/1","2022/1/1"),
  date_end = c("2022/1/11","2022/1/5","2022/1/8","2022/1/8"),
  city= c("NY","NY", "LA", "NY"),
  squad=c("a","a","b","b"),
  count_A=c(1,2,2,1),
  count_B=c(1,3,1,3)
)
```

## Code attempt

I want to do in data table something like the following code in dplyr:

```
if(DT1$city == DT2$city & DT1$squad == DT2$squad &
   DT1$date %in% seq(DT2$date_start,DT2$date_end))
{
   DT1$counter_A=DT2$counter_A
   DT1$counter_B=DT2$counter_B
} else {
    "Nothing"
}
```

Comment: Is Squad relevant to the join but City irrelevant?

Comment: @JonSpring squad and city are relevant for join.

Comment: I'm confused by the third row of desired output. Jan 9 is only in the first DT2 row range, but that's a different squad.  And row 3 of DT2 is out of date range.

Comment: oh yes there is a mistake on the 3rd line of output, I will correct..

Comment: @JonSpring Indeed, should read "0" instead of "10".

Comment: the 2nd line is okay, it corresponds to the 4th line of DT2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an addition to [Jon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6851825/jon-spring) answer:

Provided you have changed the columns with date information to an appropriate date type like he suggested, you can do the following within `data.table`.

```
setkey(DT1, "city", "squad")
setkey(DT2, "city", "squad")
dt.result <- DT1[DT2]
dt.result[, flag:=1*(work_day >= date_start & work_day <= date_end)]
dt.result[, .(ct_A=sum(count_A*flag), ct_B=sum(count_B*flag)), by=c("work_day", "city", "squad")]

     work_day city squad ct_A ct_B
1: 2022-01-09   LA     b    0    0
2: 2022-01-05   NY     a    3    4
3: 2022-01-07   NY     a    1    1
4: 2022-01-06   NY     b    1    3
```

The "ugly" construction with the flag column is only necessary in order to list combinations with zero score.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "non-equi join," in the sense that you want to match workday to the range of start-end in the other table. You should find lots of answers on stack overflow like this one: [Non-equi join of dates using data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074525/non-equi-join-of-dates-using-data-table).

What's perhaps a little unusual is showing the third line when it is not matched in the other table. If that is in fact desired you could fix it by wrapping the result in another join. Here's a dplyr approach. (the CRAN version of dplyr does not yet support non-equi joins but looks like it will in the next update. We can get around that by doing a full join and filtering.)

```
# you'll want to fix these regardless, since you can't calculate on text dates
DT1$work_day = as.Date(DT1$work_day)
DT2$date_start = as.Date(DT2$date_start)
DT2$date_end = as.Date(DT2$date_end)


DT1 %>%
  left_join(DT1 %>%  # only necessary to show result 3
    left_join(DT2, by = c("city", "squad")) %>%
    filter(work_day >= date_start, work_day <= date_end) %>%
    group_by(work_day, squad) %>%
    summarize(across(count_A:count_B, sum))) %>%
  mutate(across(count_A:count_B, ~coalesce(.x, 0)))
```

Result

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'work_day'. You can override using the `.groups`
argument.
Joining, by = c("work_day", "squad")
     work_day city squad count_A count_B
1: 2022-01-05   NY     a       3       4
2: 2022-01-06   NY     b       1       3
3: 2022-01-09   LA     b       0       0
4: 2022-01-07   NY     a       1       1
```

Comment: I will try the non-equi join of data table. The syntax seems simpler to me.